# keyboard displays in simulator on one machine, and not on another

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, libraries

So I just switched the keyboard type for the three textViews I have on one of my viewControllers to use the Number Pad keyboard. I also added a library (not a cocoapod) for a custom ScrollView object that I added to the view; the Scrollview makes all subviews scroll up/down to respond to instances of the keyboard being displayed onscreen.

It displays fine when I run the code on my machine's simulators (simulators for iPhones 5s and 6.) But when the other guy on the project tries it, the keyboard shows up briefly on the 5s simulator before hiding. On his simulator for the 6, the keyboard doesn't appear at all.

Could it be the custom Scrollview screwing with the UI? I'll post a link to the repo..I'd post some code but aside from this object, I can't think of anything else that could be responsible.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tap into a textfield and the keyboard does not appear, hit command+k on your physical keyboard to bring up the simulator one.  You will still be able to type with your physical keyboard but the simulator one will come up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `command+shift+k`. That turns on and off the simulated hardware keyboard. I have had it fix this kind of issue before, even when I didn't realize I had it turned on.